# In Azure, when is it necessary to update the size of all VMs in an availability set, given you must update at least one?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

[Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/resize-vm#use-powershell-to-resize-a-vm-in-an-availability-set) for changing virtual machine sizes suggests that you might have to "update the size of other VMs in the availability set after one VM has been resized." The example provided then shows how one might resize all VMs in an availability set, implying that one should deallocate and resize all VMs in an availability set, even if you have to resize just one.

When or why exactly are such steps necessary? (Or am I misreading the documentation?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure VM hardware is organised into hardware clusters, each cluster can support certain VM SKU's. An availability set must sit within the same hardware cluster.

If you resize one VM in you Availability Set to a different size to the rest of the set, but that size is available in the same hardware cluster then that is fine, nothing needs to be done. However, if your chosen size is on a different hardware cluster then you will need to change all of your VM's in the set to use a size supported by that cluster. You will also need to de-allocate all your VMs before resizing so it can be moved.

Generally it is recommended to keep all VMs in an availability set the same size if you can.